# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application when importing Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Both versions of Python and Tensorflow are 64bit as I have seen a lot of suggestions regarding this.
Here is the Traceback:

```
    >>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Robert Cini\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\Robert Cini\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Can you provide some information on your environment?

Comment: What information do you require? I am running Windows on 64 bit architecture, running commands on CMD as Administrator.

Comment: What packages do you have installed, for example?

Comment: numpy, matplotlib, cython, pip, jupyter